# VS Code IntelliSense not working for Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code and Unity and am having some problems.
When i type code [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFwCe.png) the intelliSense for Unity doesn't show up.
I know this topic has been discussed many times, but I'm currently but i tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. The last error that i can find is this one:
["Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Tentative de chargement d'un programme de format incorrect. (0x8007000B)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELaXr.png) and i'm not competent enough to resolve this by myself and more importantly i'm not sure if it's related.

Comment: Have you installed a Unity extension for VSCode?

Comment: Yes I did. I installed : Unity code, Unity code snippets, Unity dev pac, Unity Tools and unity ToolBox.

Comment: What does the Omnisharp output say in the terminal tab in VS Code?

Comment: The message i get is:
OmniSharp server started with .NET 6.0.302

    Path: c:\Users\scend\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.25.0-win32-x64\.omnisharp\1.39.0-net6.0\OmniSharp.dll
    PID: 28344

Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Tentative de chargement d'un programme de format incorrect. (0x8007000B)

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio it sometimes helps to regenerate the project files:

In Unity:

Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> "Regenerate project files"

Maybe it also works for VS Code. Make also sure "Visual Studio Code" is selected as "External Script Editor" before regenerating.

Comment: I think it resolved itself. I opened VS Code later and everything worked perfectly and I don't know why, but I'll take it. Thank you for your help, you're all kind peoples. I'm going to delete my question now because I don't think it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need .NET framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack.
Try this

1. Uninstall all extension on VSCode.
2. Close VSCode and Unity.
3. Install .NET framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack.
4. Open Unity and set VSCode as the code editor.
5. Open VSCode from Unity.
6. Install the Omnisharp extension.

Source: https://vionixstudio.com/2021/11/02/unity-visual-studio-code/

Comment: I think it resolved itself. I opened VS Code later and everything worked perfectly and I don't know why, but I'll take it. Thank you for your help, you're all kind peoples. I'm going to delete my question now because I don't think it will help others.